# carrierwave same callback for multiple uploaders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've got a rails application with multiples uploaders.
In each uploaders I'd like a function to be executed after each file delete.
I can put a trigger and a callback in each uploader :

```
 after :remove, :remove_dir
 def remove_dir
    FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}", :force => true)
 end
```

But this is not really smart...
There is probably a better way to do that ????

Comment: You could make all uploaders inherit from a common parent uploader where this code would be placed.

Comment: Of course !!! That's a very basic and fully working solution.

Comment: In fact, I didn't succeded with class inheritance : Uploaders allready inherits the Carrierwave class.
So I did it by including a module and then it works.
You may want to update your answer ?

Comment: Then you could make the parent class inherit from Carrierwave class!

Comment: You're right ! But isn't it simpler to add my methode to the Carrierwave class by using the initializers (carrierwav.rb) file?
(to be exact it's the "Base" class in "Uploader" module inside "Carrierwave" module)
Thanks

Comment: Didn't think about this one, good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've finally found a convenient solution thanks to [Michal Szyndel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422778/michal-szyndel) that helped me and gave me good clues :

Each uploaders inherit from `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base`, so I add a callback to it through the carrierwave's initializer file(carrierwave.rb), and then I call it thanks to a trigger located in the concerned uploaders.

in carrierwave.rb :

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    class Base
      def remove_dir
        path = "#{Rails.root}/public/"+store_dir
        FileUtils.remove_dir(path, :force => true) if Dir[path+'/*'].empty?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in concerned uploaders :

```
after :remove, :remove_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to create a parent class for all uploader and then inherit other uploaders from it.

If you place a callback in the parent class it will be executed by all the children. Parent class should of course inherit from `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base`

Another solution would be to create a module and include it in all uploader classes.